# Run thousands of queries on ~60gb of logfiles

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I have a month worth of logfiles (~60gb uncompressed) and I need to run about 1000 thousand queries on these logfiles. Each logfile is ~68MB compressed with gzip.

For testing purpose I have installed Hadoop and Hive in pseudo-distributed mode on our test server (8core, 32gb ram) and I have loaded the logfiles in a hive table which looks somewhat like this:

> date, time, userid, channel

And I have a file with about 1000 timeframes like this:

> date, time-start, time-end
>
> 01_01_2015, 08:05:31, 08:09:54
>
> 01_01_2015, 08:54:10, 08:54:30
>
> ...
>
> 02_01_2015, 08:15:14, 08:20:48
>
> ...

[edit:] The timeframes on a single day are non-overlapping and with precision in seconds. They can be as short as 10 seconds and as long as several minutes.

I want to find out how many unique user were on my site during these exact timeframes.
With each of these timeframes being unique.

My question is what would be the most time efficient way of handling such a task? Running a thousand different queries in Hive seems like a terrible way of doing this.

The alternative would be to bundle say 50-100 queries into one to avoid too much overhead from creating jobs etc., would that work better? And is there a limit how long a query can be in Hive?

While Im interested in how this could be done with Hadoop, I'm also open for other suggestions (especially considering this runs in pseudo-distributed).

Answer (score 0):

Are the timeframes overlapping?  If so, would 1-minute chunks of the log be a reasonable way to chunk the data?  That is would there be dozens or hundreds of rows per minute and all the timeframes have a resolution of one minute?  If not one minute, maybe one hour?

Summarize the data in each 1-minute chunk; put the results in another database table.  Then write queries against that table.

That would be the MySQL way to do it, probably in a single machine.

**Edit** (based on OP's edit showing that ranges are non-overlapping and not conveniently divided):

Given that the ranges are non-overlapping, you should aim for doing the work in a single pass.

I would pick between a Perl/PHP program that does all the work, versus 1000 sql calls with

```
INSERT INTO SummaryTable
SELECT MIN(ts), MAX(ts), SUM(...), COUNT(...)
    FROM ... 
    WHERE ts BETWEEN...
```

(This assumes an index on ts.)  That would be simple enough and fast enough -- It would run only slightly slower than the time it takes to read that much disk.

But... Why even put the *raw* data into a database table?  That is a lot of work, with perhaps no long-term benefit.  So, I am back to writing a Perl script to read the log file, doing the work as it goes.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your suggestion, I've added more detailed information about the timeframes in my original question. The timeframes dont overlap though.

Comment: Well I'm not actually putting them in a relational database, Hive just projects table metadata onto the raw data stored in Hadoops filesystem. Which is fairly fast and writing the script didnt take too long. For now I have created a partitioned table on which I want to run a query for each partition. Each query consisting of a bunch timeframes, hence my question if theres a length-limit for hive queries. Do you really think a perlscript using regex to extract certain key-value pairs from millions of rows and comparing each of them with thousands of timeframe-values would be faster?

Comment: Sort the non-overlapping timeframes, then you only need to do one compare per row of input.  (I have no input on Hive.)

Comment: Only one compare per row? Could you elaborate? I quite underestimated the amount of data btw. its actually about 250GB uncompressed.

Comment: Once you have sorted the non-overlapping timeframes, scan through the raw data, comparing each ts in it to the end_time in the "current" timeframe.  Compute what you need, then move on to the next row.  Eventually you will pass the end_time, at which point, fetch the next timeframe.  So the number of compares equals the number of rows in the 250GB (perhaps plus 1000).  The "plus 1000" is because you will probably make 2 compares to exit one timeframe and enter the next.